# Where condition inside HTML.erb file using Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an .html.erb file which is to print the customer details on a form.
In my database table "customers" there are "User_id" filed and "creater_id" field is there. I want to print the customer_name of the customer where user_id eqaul to creater_id.
How to implement it into my html file ?

Comment: This is what want to get done in Rails : SELECT customer.firstname WHERE customer.user_id=customer.creater_id.

Comment: Can you specified your model relationship.? So that i can give you better answer.

Comment: @SajjadMurtaza : Sorry dude I am new to Rails concepts, I am working on a partially completed project. I can access and print like
            <td>
              <%= customer.firstname %> 
            </td>
but what I need here is now to print based on a conditon "SELECT customer.firstname WHERE customer.user_id=customer.creater_id"

Comment: could my answer help you? or is your problem still existing?

Answer (score 0):

don't write conditions into the partial. thats really bad and creates code nobody want to take care of them.

use scopes or methods for this

for rails 3

```
class MyModel
  scope :better, where(field:'better')
end
```

and in your view

```
@my_model_instance.better.each.....
```

**update:**

for your customer model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :user_is_creator, where('user_id=creater_id')
end
```

if you have in your controller a instance variable like `@customer` so use it with this:

```
@customer = Customer.user_is_creator
```

after this you can iterate in your view about the collection like

```
<%@customer.each do |customer|%>
  <%=customer.firstname%>
<%-end-%>
```

Comment: Sorry dude I am new to Rails concepts, I am working on a partially completed project. I can access and print like <td> <%= customer.firstname %> </td> but what I need here is now to print based on a conditon "SELECT customer.firstname WHERE customer.user_id=customer.creater_id"

Comment: your model is called customer? so your table is called customers? is that right?

Comment: yse my model name is  (customer.rb) and table name is (customers).

Comment: Still showing error like "undefined method `user_is_creator' for #<Class:0x007f116b69cf20>

Extracted source (around line #49):
@type=1
            @customer = Customer.user_is_creator
            @customers=Customer.where(devicemodel_id: [@type]);
        end
      end

Comment: did you add `scope :user_is_creator, where('user_id=creater_id')` to your customer model?

Comment: hm. it looks like your customer class is not an activerecord class. i didnt added it in my answer. but it has to be declared like `class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base`